# EF core model include property from parent entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, ef-core-3.0

In Entity Framework Core I have this context where a project has some tasks, and each task has some activities.
In a view of recent activities, I would like to add the project title for each activity, which is accesible through activity.task.projetct.title.

If I load my activity with

```
_context.Activities.FindAsync(id);
```

the activity.Task is null.

How do I get EF to (lazy) load the task, and the task's project to get the title?

If I user eager loading with

```
var activity = await _context.Activities
   .Include(a => a.Task).ThenInclude(f => f.Project)
   .FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Id == id);
```

I get this exception:

> JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected which is not
>   supported. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is
>   larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32.

The thing is I don't want to deep load tasks and project, just a shallow load to get first level properties.

Comment: In a.Task is a also a Task, or in f.Project is f also a project ? Or are their activities ?
Somehow you create circle reference among those tables. EF can handle that, it just would load all. But as JSON said: JSON can not ! It's actually same as a "stackoverflow" due tu recursion. And the depth of recursion is limited to 32.
It's not an EF problem, it's a problem of your data-transfer via JSON.

Comment: a is an Activity, Activities are children of Tasks, Tasks owns Activities, hence the circular. Point is, I don't care about Tasks (other) activities in this scenario.

Comment: Why you add "Include" if you don't care ? And no: A simple parent-child relation cannot cause circularity. Rather a Self-Reference can cause it.If one record is holding a reference to another record in the same table, you can end up at the start-record. This record chain is limited to 32 in JSON, even if there is no circularity at all.

Comment: Let's take it a step back. Is it expected behaviour, in a simple parent child relationship, that loading a child (Activity in first example) does NOT automagically load the parent, and if yes - what does it take to load the parent (without loading parents other children and parents parent)?

Comment: For EF it is. That's called *relationship fixup*. If both parent and child are attached to the context and they have a circular reference, then both of their navigation properties are populated. For a serializer that's an infinite depth of the object graph. You have to configure the serializer to ignore reference loops.

Comment: @GertArnold thanks for your input, indeed the problem is with serialization.
I have decorated all back-reference (from child to parent) properties with [JsonIgnore], but still get the exception.
Any idea how to configure the serializer?

Comment: The error as it turns out, is caused by [JsonIgnore] being ignored. My web api has been ported to netcore 3.0. The Model classes are in a netstandard 2.0 library using newtonsoft.json. I had to remove newtonsoft.json and install system.text.json. Now, [JsonIgnore] is effective again.

Comment: Just to be complete for EF. The difference from a related Entity is beeing loaded immediatly or later on, is only indicated by marking the property as virtual.
The "include" makes only sense on virtual properties, otherwise, it's the default to "include" - to load it in the first query.

Comment: @Gert Arnold The problem is System.Text.Json has no way of configuring ignoring reference loops as Newtonsof has. And System.Text.Json is the default json serializer in .net core 3.